# Como utilizar valores de una funcion de callback dentro de otra funcion de callback?

Tags: javascript, html, callback

Tengo dos select en mi HTML uno del que tomo un anno y otro que en dependencia de la seleccion hago una determinada consulta ajax... para tomar los datos del los selects utilice 2 eventListeners uno que se ejecuta cuando cambio las selecciones.. Quiero utilizar el valor del anno que selecciono como parametro en la funcion que hace la llamada ajax(en la parte de `if(opcion.value == 1){** contenido**}` cuando selecciono la opcion del segundo select ), pero eh estado probando cosas y no puedo pasar el valor del anno de las funciones de una funcion de callback a otra... de hecho cuando lo paso como parametro como en el ejemplo me devuelve lo siguiente..

```
Event {isTrusted: true, type: "change", target: select#select, currentTarget: select#select, eventPhase: 2, …}
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

  //valor del anno en en select
  var selectAnno = document.getElementById("annos");

  let annoSeleccionado = "";
  selectAnno.addEventListener('change', function (annoSeleccionado) {

    annoSeleccionado = parseInt(this.options[selectAnno.selectedIndex].value);
    console.log(annoSeleccionado);
  });


  //selecciono el menu lateral donde se dibujan los campos relativos
  var menuLateral = document.querySelector('#lateral');
  var encabezado = document.querySelector('#encabezado');

  //selecciono el select
  var valorseleccionado = document.getElementById('select');

  //tomo el valor del select cuando cambie y muesto los datos de interes
  valorseleccionado.addEventListener('change', function (annoSeleccionado) {
    var opcion = this.options[select.selectedIndex];

    if (opcion.value == 1) {

      funcionAjax(annoSeleccionado)

      encabezado.innerHTML = `
    <th>Anno gestione</th>
    <th>Capitolo</th>
    <th>Importo</th>
    <th>% aggio</th>
    <th>% iva su aggio</th>`;

      menuLateral.innerHTML = `
    <div class='elementos'>
        <label for='capitolo'>Capitolo</label>
        <input name='capitolo' id="buscar" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class='elementos'>
        <label for='descrizione'>Descrizione</label>
        <input name="descrizione"  type="text">
    </div>`
    }
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='querys'>
    <div class='elementos'>
      <label for="SelAnno">Anno Gestion</label>
      <select name='SelAnno' id='annos'>
        <option>2019</option>
        <option>2018</option>
        <option>2017</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id='querys'>
    <div class='elementos'>
      <label for='pruebas'>Tipo de consulta</label>
      <select name="pruebas" id="select">
        <option>Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">Prevision</option>
        <option value="2">Otros datos</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='menulateral ' id='lateral'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lo que he hecho hasta ahora no es muy optimo agrege un input hidden y agregue el valor del anno en una funcion y desde la otro tomo el valor de este campo pero esta solucion no me gusta ni un poco...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las funciones callback de los eventos reciben como parámetro el evento en sí (por eso ves un objeto de la clase `Event`). Pero puedes simplemente usar una clausura:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  //Declaramos la variable global
  let annoSeleccionado = "";
  //valor del anno en en select
  const selectAnno = document.getElementById("annos");

  selectAnno.addEventListener('change', function () {
    //podemos acceder a la variable de la función aquí, creando una clausura
    annoSeleccionado = parseInt(this.options[selectAnno.selectedIndex].value);
    console.log('Hemos seleccionado el año', annoSeleccionado);
  });

  //selecciono el select
  var valorseleccionado = document.getElementById('select');

  //tomo el valor del select cuando cambie y muesto los datos de interes
  valorseleccionado.addEventListener('change', function () {
    const opcion = this.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    //de nuevo podemos acceder a la variable sin problemas
    console.log('Se ha seleccionado la combinación', annoSeleccionado,'y', opcion);
    //Aquí podríamos llamar a otra función, pasándole los parámetros
    //funcionAjax(annoSeleccionado,opcion);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='querys'>
    <div class='elementos'>
      <label for="SelAnno">Anno Gestion</label>
      <select name='SelAnno' id='annos'>
      <option value="-1">Selecciona Año</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id='querys'>
    <div class='elementos'>
      <label for='pruebas'>Tipo de consulta</label>
      <select name="pruebas" id="select">
        <option>Selecciona</option>
        <option value="1">Prevision</option>
        <option value="2">Otros datos</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class='menulateral ' id='lateral'>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No conocemos exactamente el uso que le quieres dar a tus funciones callback, pero existen otras soluciones un poco más complejas:

Usando [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) puedes añadir parámetros previos a una función:

```js
function prueba(uno,dos) {
  console.log('He recibido los parámetros',uno,'y',dos.constructor);
}

let callback = prueba.bind(null,'Hola');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',callback);
```

```html
<button>Click<button>
```

O puedes puedes tener una función de mayor orden para generar una clausura previa:

```js
function generaCallback(uno) {

  return function(dos) {
    console.log(uno, dos);
  }
}

const callback = generaCallback('hola');

callback('Mundo');
```

Comment: He añadido otras posibles formas de solucionar el problema, por si te interesa

Comment: Gracias @Pablo Lozano no estoy claro aun de como funciona pero es exactamente como dices

Comment: Vale muchas gracias estoy viendo las otras posibles soliciones :)